# RethinkDB update value using join result

Tags: join, rethinkdb

I have a structure of 3 tables on my rethinkdb.

- feed - have the product name and coverage information

> { "product" : "name-x",
>     "coverage" : "3%" }

- clean - a list of synonymous from the product name

> { "product" : "name-x",
>     "synonymous" : ["name-x","X","product-x"] }

- devices - a list of devices and some extra informations

> { "product" : "product-x",
>     "coverage" : "0%" }, { "product" : "product-y", "coverage" : "1%" }, { "product" : "product-x",
>     "coverage" : "0%" }

We are going to update the **feed** table regularly and then run a query to update the **devices** tables.

Doing the following, I can merge all tables and get the correct coverage from each device.

```
r.db('devices').table('cleaning').innerJoin(r.db('devices').table('feed'),
function(cleaningRow, feedRow) {
   return cleaningRow('synonyms').contains(feedRow('product'))
}).zip().innerJoin(r.db('devices').table('devices').hasFields('product'),
function(mergeRow, devicesRow) {
   return mergeRow('synonyms').contains(devicesRow('product'))
}).zip()
```

How can I update the **devices** table with the correct information? For now, I was able to only get the value with the query.

---

The devices table is quite large, and we don't have control on how the product name will be, that's why we are using the "cleaning" table. Also, I can have multiple ocurrence of the "same" device on the **devices** table.

Answer (score 1):

```
r.db("dbName")
 .table("tblName").innerJoin(
   r.db("dbName").table("tblName1"), function(tl, path){
     return tblName("value1").eq(path("value1"));
   }
 ).map({  
filterkey: r.row("left")("filterkey")
})
```